# Java - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

Tags: java

I'm having this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

This is the code in error:

```
public List<String> customPrefixes(PermissionUser u)
{
    List returnlist = new ArrayList();
    for (String k : u.getAllPermissions().keySet()) {
        List perms = (List)u.getAllPermissions().get(k);
        for (String s : perms) {
            String[] split = s.split(".");
            if ((split.length >= 3) && 
              (split[0].equalsIgnoreCase("plugin")) && 
              (split[1].equalsIgnoreCase("prefix"))) {
                returnlist.add(split[2]);
            }
        }
    }
    return returnlist;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this :

```
public List<String> customPrefixes(PermissionUser u)
  {
    List<String> returnlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String k : u.getAllPermissions().keySet()) {
      List<String> perms = (List<String>)(u.getAllPermissions()).get(k);
      for (String s : perms) {
        String[] split = s.split(".");
        if ((split.length >= 3) &&
          (split[0].equalsIgnoreCase("plugin")) &&
          (split[1].equalsIgnoreCase("prefix"))) {
          returnlist.add(split[2]);
        }
      }

    }

    return returnlist;
  }
```

You were missing `"<String>"` in the List declaration

Comment: Are you sure that `u.getAllPermissions()` returns something that can be cast to `List<String>`?

Comment: PermissionUser seems to be a custom class, so this is up to the composer of this question. He claims that it does

Comment: If it can't be, the next error he'll get will be class cast exception

Comment: Please rephrase your comment, as i have not downvoted anybody, i don't understand what you mean

Comment: Thank you, @LenaBru I feel so dumb about forgetting about the <String>. (facepalm). Correct answer.

Comment: @LenaBru Misunderstood you :) Now after you've explained your answer, you get my +1.

Comment: @PlayinCODMC make note i put brackets on (u.getAllPermissions) as i want to cast the getAllPermissions return type, and not u

Answer (score 1):

I think you're casting is wrong..

What is u.getAllPermissions().get(k); should return? List of something?
if it does so you need to add type of the generic list

```
List<String> perms = (List<String>)u.getAllPermissions().get(k);
```

If that doesn't work you can also try to do

```
for (Object o : perms) {
 String s = o.toString();
 .....
}
```

Hope that helps.. If not answer my question and it will be easier to help

Comment: Casting it to `Object` works but if we had `List<Foo>` instead of `List<String>` we will loose the ability to call methods available on `Foo` object inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error can be the way you have initialized your container; as a case in point;
you have initialize list2 as below:

```
List list2 = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```

instead of

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```

So, you are looping over a wrong type of container ( if we can call this a container) as below :

```
for(Integer x:list2){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
```

Thus, you need to revise the way you have initialize your container ( here is a list) and there is no problem with your datatype, etc.