# How to obtain data and iterate over arraylist returned as an object?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, iteration

In my app I created an ArrayList in some servlet which was assigned using request.setAttribute() as 'testList'. Then request was forwarded to jsp page.
Inside jsp page I want to retrieve whole ArrayList and iterate over it.

I used getAttribute(), but after that I cannot retrieve an ArrayList from that object.

An ArrayList contains objects TestObject created by me in another class (which was imported properly). I would like to get access to it by iteration over ArrayList.

```
Object testList = request.getAttribute("testList");
ArrayList<TestObject> localList = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
localList = testList;
//Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to ArrayList<TestObject>
```

What is a best practice to obtain data from Object to ArrayList?

Should I use a cast (IDE warns: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList)?
Or generics?
Or... ?

Comment: Just so you know, using `localList = new ArrayList<>()` and then `localList = testlist` doesn't copy the testlist to the newly created `ArrayList`. It just discards it and assigns a reference to the existing testlist to `localList`, so that `testlist` and `localList` point to the same list.

Comment: What you need is [a cast](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853404/java-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-element-type-object-to-string)

Comment: You've jumped into the deep end without getting your feet wet first. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks, I'm in the beginning of learning Java, very often I forgot some principals like that. Argh!

Comment: @chb Yes, I looks like that. Thanks for a helpful link to generics subject. I have to study it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a cast. The defensive solution checks that the type is correct before casting:

```
    Object testList = request.getAttribute("testList");
    if (testList instanceof Collection) {
        for (Object obj : (Collection<?>) testList) {
            if (obj instanceof TestObject) {
                TestObject currentTestObject = (TestObject) obj;
                // Do something with currentTestObject
            }
        }
    }
```

To iterate over the list returned from `request.getAttribute` you only need to assume it is a `Collection`, not necessarily `ArrayList`. Since `ArrayList` implements the `Collection` interface the above code will work with `ArrayList` and with other collection types too. If you only want it to work with `List` or only `ArrayList`, just use one of those types instead of `Collection` in the code.

Consider adding `else` parts to the `if` statements and issue a log message and do some other appropriate action if a runtime type wasn’t as expected.

If you are sure you always get an `ArrayList<TestObject>`, you may omit the checks:

```
    Collection<TestObject> testList = (Collection<TestObject>) request.getAttribute("testList");
    for (TestObject currentTestObject : testList) {
        // Do something with currentTestObject
    }
```

This is somewhat simpler.

**Link:** [Object Type Casting in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting)

Comment: Thanks for that answer! I will try it out and I'll let you know about results and thoughts :)

Answer (score -2):

You can pass your object to your ArrayList constructor :

```
Object testList = request.getAttribute("testList");
ArrayList<TestObject> localList = new ArrayList<TestObject>(testList);
```

Comment: It won't work - 'The constructor ArrayList<TestBox>(Object) is undefined'. I think you thought to use 'public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)' constructor. But in this case 'testList' is still an object not an ArrayList.